# Xcode 4 distribution release problem

Tags: xcode4

I have problem with releasing my application to app store. I did everything like Xcode 3.x but I don't have any build folder on my app-folder. Where is it?

Comment: We're nowhere near as excited about the problem you're describing as you are. In case you want them back, I've moved all your exclamation marks here: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your (open in xcode editor)`yourProject.xcodeproj` and search for `build location` string,

you will see the directory location to your build path...

Could be like that..

```
/Users/Momeks/Desktop/myapplication/builds
```

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4 does everything for you now. Choose Archive from the Product menu. This will build and archive your app into the Organizer. Now select submit. Choose your app store provisioning profile for the code sign and click submit. Xcode will upload and submit your app to iTunes connect.

The app is forever archived in Xcode now, *with* its debug symbols. Ace.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Submit button in the Organizer after Archiving your app.